# Moshi map nested JSON value to field

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

Is there any way to map nested JSON value to field without additional classes? I have a JSON response

```
{
    "title": "Warriors",
    "artist": "Imagine Dragons",
    "apple_music": {
        "url": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/warriors/1440831203?app=music&at=1000l33QU&i=1440831624&mt=1",
        "discNumber": 1,
        "genreNames": [
            "Alternative",
            "Music"
        ],
    }
}
```

But from `apple_music` I need only `url` value. So I decided to create Kotlin data class and tried option with `@Json` annotation

```
data class Song(
    val title: String,
    val artist: String,
    @Json(name = "apple_music.url")
    val appleMusicUrl: String
)
```

However, this doesn't work. 
It throws an exception at runtime

```
Required value 'appleMusicUrl' (JSON name 'apple_music.url') missing at $
```

The code below is working

```
data class Song(
    val title: String,
    val artist: String,
    @Json(name = "apple_music")
    val appleMusic: AppleMusic
)

data class AppleMusic(val url: String)
```

I have several nested values and creating extra classes for them is quite overblowing. Is there any better ways than creating nested class for `apple_music` node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is with [alternate type adapters using @JsonQualifier](https://github.com/square/moshi#alternate-type-adapters-with-jsonqualifier). For example:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class AppleMusicUrl

data class Song(
    val title: String,
    val artist: String,
    @AppleMusicUrl
    val appleMusicUrl: String
)

@FromJson
@AppleMusicUrl
fun fromJson(json: Map<String, Any?>): String {
    return json.getValue("url") as String
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had to wrap `fromJson` into adapter with `@ToJson` method as well and register this adapter in moshi builder

Comment: I just thought there is a way to be done automatically. The idea has been taken from MapStruct mapper for java [example](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mappings-with-several-source-parameters)

Comment: can you please post the whole code for this @martaisty